# Can Bluetooth LE server send notification to client using Bluetooth?

Tags: c#, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have created Bluetooth LE server in C#, I am able to send file data from BLE server to the client using notification service, but the file transfer rate is very slow, because of BLE.
SO, Can we use Bluetooth for sending Notification to client in the BLE setup?

Comment: If your Bluetooth devices support Classci Bluetooth - yes. And BLE was developed for other things, not for file (or any other big data) transferring. For big data - use Classic Bluetooth instead.

Comment: Using BLE you can get up to 1.4 Mbit/s if used optimally. You haven't given us any information at all on your setup except that you use C# for programming. But yes, notifications can of course be used since it's part of the standard.

Comment: yes, I agree that BLE is supposed to use for file sending, but I have to do it, how can we use classic Bluetooth for sending notification to BLE client from BLE server?@Mike Petrichenko